# Pass multiple filters with multiple values in a query string (REST)

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I originally posted multiple filters containing multiple values in JSON as part of my GET request but I believe this is bad practise, so I changed it to a POST but I don't like it as getting results from a query has nothing to do with a POST so I guess I'll have to use a query string

Most filter examples I have found are either using one filter or one value, but I am looking as to whether or not there is a best practise to pass multiple filters with multiple values for filtering as a single parameter in the query string.

For example, this is a basic one which looks for all cars that are red

GET /cars?color=red

But what if I wanted to look for all cars that are

red, blue or green and
have 2 seats or less and
their brand name starts with b and
can be bought in the US, UK or Germany

Would the following be ok?

http://myserver/api/cars?color=red|blue|green¬seats<=2¬brand[startswith]b¬country=USA|UK|Germany

I'm suggesting the use of the:

1. `|` character as a separator between each values for a given filter
2. `¬` character as a separator between each filters
3. [startsWith] to handle the search type, but could contain [=, <=, >=, <>, [contains],[endswith], etc...

This would then be parsed in the server end and the relevant filters would be build accordingly based on the provided values

Hope this make sense but I'm really interested as to whether or not there is a standard/best practise used for such scenarios with REST in mind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in most design questions, the key is having a consistent design for all your APIs. You can follow certain well-known guidelines/standards to make your API easily discoverable.

For example, take a look at OData. The "Queries" section on [this page](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/) is relevant to your question. Here's an example:

```
https://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$top=2 &amp; $select=FirstName, LastName &amp; $filter=Trips/any(d:d/Budget gt 3000)
```

Another option is the OpenSearch standard. The relevant section is [here](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1/Draft_5#OpenSearch_URL_template_syntax). Here's an example:

```
https://opensearch.php?recordSchema=html&query=dc.creator any Mill* Grad*
```

Another interesting option is GraphQL, which makes it easier to map query parameters to data fetch parameters. It uses a filter payload instead of query parameters. See the spec here: [GraphQL Spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in some sort of direction. I will read more about both and will update. As a matter of interest, as we are using neither of these standards, is there a way to just use the "parsing" mechanism just on the query string?

Comment: @Thierry You can find libraries for many of these standards, for example, [Microsoft OData stack](https://odata.github.io/). You can import the library and just use its provided classes to parse the query string.

Comment: As we have restrictions on the libraries we can use, I wasn't allowed to use the `Microsoft OData stack` so based on our requirements, I ended up writing our own parsing filtering function which was quite simple to be honest which handles scenarios such as (not encoded): `Company equals 'AL' and Country contains 'US,UK,France'...` - It supports all the standards operand i.e. StartsWith, EndsWith, NotEqual, etc.. and `OR` requirements are based on whether the value contains a comma within the value and it works just as expected but thanks again for the suggestions.